# How to find/list the checked-in files in current view?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have:

1. a view created as dynamic view
2. Files which are checkout or checked-in.

Now I want know the list of files checked-in in view.
What command should I use?

Comment: Are you asking for files checked in by the user in a certain timeframe? What is the question that drives the question? In other words, what question is being asked that requires a list of checked-in files?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use [`cleartool ls`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/cs/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ls.htm), and grep for /main/LATEST (or just LATEST if you don't care of the branch selected, depending on your config spec)

```
cleartool ls -r -view|grep LATEST
```

Only versioned checked-in file would be listed that way.

---

Using [`cleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/da/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) is also a possibility, but would list versions even for files which are checked out, which is not what you want.
See [those examples](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/da/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) to illustrate the difference.

> ### to list element versions on a branch but exclude checkedout versions
>
> - The first example lists all element versions including any CHECKEDOUT versions.
> - The second example shows how to list all element versions, but excluding any CHECKEDOUT versions.

```
EXAMPLE 1:
> cleartool find . -version "brtype(bugfix)" -print
./a.c@@/main/bugfix/0
./a.c@@/main/bugfix/1
./a.c@@/main/bugfix/2
./a.c@@/main/bugfix/CHECKEDOUT
./golf.c@@/main/bugfix/0
./golf.c@@/main/bugfix/1

EXAMPLE 2
> cleartool find . -version "brtype(bugfix)" -print | grep -v CHECKEDOUT
./a.c@@/main/bugfix/0
./a.c@@/main/bugfix/1
./a.c@@/main/bugfix/2
./golf.c@@/main/bugfix/0
./golf.c@@/main/bugfix/1
```